# How to create a hectare raster from vector input data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, rasterization

I have a vector file containing points with an attributed value (no. of employes at that location). I need to create a hectare raster with the sum of employes for each grid cell. I'm using QGIS and have so far played around with gdal_rasterize gdal_grid but with no success. I'm not even sure if I'm looking at the right tool.
Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know how to create the hectare sized grid (using the `Vector->Research tools->Vector grid)` then you can import both the point shapefile and the grid polygons into **SpatiaLite** and with an aggregate query get the totals as an attribute column in each grid sqare. For example if you have an id column in the grid polygon layer, and a num_employees column in the points layer, then:

Using spatialite, import the two shapefiles:

```
.loadshp employee_points points utf-8 4326
.loadshp grid grid utf-8 4326
```

Add new columns in the grid layer for the totals. You can also get averages, etc while you're at it...

```
ALTER TABLE grid ADD COLUMN ttl_employees INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE grid ADD COLUMN avg_employees INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE grid ADD COLUMN cnt_pts INTEGER;
```

Now do the UPDATE to populate those columns with a SELECT query that uses the SQL aggregate "SUM" and the ST_Contains() function. The second part of the WHERE clause matches each select to the correct row in the outer UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE grid SET ttl_employees=(
SELECT SUM(p.num_employees) 
FROM points AS p, grid AS g
WHERE ST_Contains(g.Geometry, p.Geometry) AND
g.id = grid.id
);
UPDATE grid SET avg_employees=(
SELECT AVG(p.num_employees) 
FROM points AS p, grid AS g
WHERE ST_Contains(g.Geometry, p.Geometry) AND
g.id = grid.id
);
UPDATE grid SET cnt_pts=(
SELECT COUNT(p.id) 
FROM points AS p, grid AS g
WHERE ST_Contains(g.Geometry, p.Geometry) AND
g.id = grid.id
);
```

Comment: I got the data from the provider in a hectar raster. Therefor I haven't tried your solution yet. But as it's a quite common problem, I will surely get to it in another project soon. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your initial projection, but lets assume its distance units are meters.

- You create a vector grid with QGIS using the standard vector tools or mmqgis. 1ha equals 10,000 m², therefore you need to specify your grid size (ratio) according to that.
- After you have created the grid, just conduct a spatial join which sums up the number of employees per vector grid cell.
- Then use the gdal_rasterize command to rasterize your vector grid